# Can I use an existing, in-use EC2 instance for ECS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an EC2 instance that's hosting a website. I want to create a new website and host it in a container that's hosted by ECS that uses the same EC2 instance.

Is it possible to have an EC2 instance running both websites in this way? Would ECS interfere with my original web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to customize an EC2 instance to join an ECS cluster when you don't use the ECS-optimized AMI. We often see customers doing this when they have their own OS standards and peculiar infrastructure requirements. I have rarely seen a customer re-using an existing EC2 instance in production to do this but it's technically possible to go through [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html) to enable it. My worry is that I don't know if this will break anything in your application (how is your application deployed?). Have you considered running the new application on [Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html)? With Fargate you don't have to provision infrastructure (i.e. EC2) to deploy tasks.

Comment: Yes I've looked at Fargate. My main concern is the additional spend that comes with using a new host, which won't appeal to the management. The existing application is hosted by IIS.